# Android send out generic notification instead of custom one for foreground service

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I'm trying to create a custom notification with an action for my foreground service but for some reason android keeps sending out a generic "{appname} is running in the background | tap for more information or to stop the app" notification.

What I'm doing inside my service class (onStartCommand):

Create the notification channel:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "Foreground Service Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    );
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
}
```

Create an intent (for the contentIntent) and set flags:

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_MAIN_ACTIVITY);
```

Create the pending intent for said intent:

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Create the action intent and its pending intent:

```
 Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, WebSocketService.class);
 stopIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);

 PendingIntent stopPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                    0, stopIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Create the notification itself:

```
 Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
                    .setTicker("TestTicker")
                    .setContentText("TestText")
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setWhen(0)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_delete, "Stop", stopPendingIntent);

 Notification not = notification.build();
```

Start the service:

```
startForeground(1, not);
```

I've tested this on multiple devices running different versions of Android (10, 11 and 12) but they all show the same result.
Is there anyhthing I'm overlooking? Am I setting the flags wrong on the intents?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding small icon value to the notification builder.

```
Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
```

Comment: I cannot believe that it was that simple of a fix. Thank you so much, this issue has been driving me nuts for weeks!